# How to Filter special characters or anything that doesn't matches the search String in MVC

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

i want to filter the search string entered in a way that it doesn't accept anything other than the matched string for Searching.

Here is my Controller code:

```
 public ActionResult SearchProduct(string SearchString)
            {

            FlipcartDBContextEntities db = new FlipcartDBContextEntities();


            if(ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                // if ModelState is true

                string noResult = "Search Result Not Found";
                var products = from p in db.Products select p;

                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty((SearchString).Trim()))
                {

                    products = products.Where(s => s.ProductName.Contains(SearchString));
                    return View(products.ToList());

                }

                else
                {
                    ViewBag.Message = noResult;
                    return View(new List<Product>());
                }

            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Search not successful");
            }

            return View();


        }
```

"Search Result Not Found" is displaying only for null entry..but i want it to display for any other characters that doesn't matches the search string.

How do i do that?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 if(ModelState.IsValid)
 {
     // if ModelState is true
     string noResult = "Search Result Not Found";

     //ternary expression to return a new list if Search string is null or empty
     var products = string.IsNullOrEmpty(SearchString.Trim()) 
                    ? new List<Product>() 
                    : db.Products
                        .Where(s => s.ProductName.Contains(SearchString));

     //set viewbag message if list is empty
     if(!products.Any())
     {
         ViewBag.Message = noResult;
     }
     return View(products.ToList());

 }
 else
 {
     ModelState.AddModelError("", "Search not successful");
 }
```